# Dates to be given serial number in ascending order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to arrange dates in ascending order and the provide unique serial number to each date ,

if duplicate date the the first date first next serial number.

[image]

Comment: This can be done fairly easily with COUNTIF. Can you say what you have tried so far plz?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below formula in the serial number column,

`=RANK(A1,A:A,1)+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)-1`

Drag it to the entire list. The dates has to be column A. This formula compares each date in its column and provide the rank. In your case it is the serial number. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if you found this useful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Sort the Database & use Date as Primary key. Then in next Column write this simple formula,, 
=Row () - 168 or Row(B169)-168 & finish with Ctrl +shift +enter and till end.

Please remember my Database's Range is, 
B169:C178. You please adjust the data range as you need.